# Does Terminal 2E at Charles de Gaulle airport ever close?

Tags: airports, layovers, paris, cdg, opening-hours

I have a 23:30 hours layover at Paris Terminal 2E-Charles de Gaulle airport. Arriving at 2:05pm.My connecting flight is 1:35pm the next day. 
I heard the airport will be closed from 11:30pm to 4:30am.

I don't mind waiting at the airport since I will need a visa if I decide to leave the transit area. 
I want to know if can stay at the transit area or I will be required to leave the airport because of the closure.

Also I heard there is the Sheraton Hotel inside the airport terminal 2E. Do I need to go through immigration to access this hotel?
Thanks

Comment: Please do not ask [the same question twice](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57674/23-hours-at-paris-terminal-2e-charles-de-gaulle-airport)

Comment: Voting to reopen this one since it's been edited. Voting to close the other one.

Comment: go see paris!!!

Answer (score 7):

#### Opening Hours and Sleeping

[CDG airport is open 24 hours](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/paris.htm), in the sense that you can stay inside, be it landside or airside, for 24 hours. The airport facilities however do not operate 24 hours. The opening hours of most shops and lounges seem to be between 06:30 and 23:00, some lounges have shorter opening hours and others push 06:00 to 23:30. The [EasyCDG website has a page on lounges](http://easycdg.com/airport-guide/airline-lounges-paris-cdg/), and [one on shopping facilities](http://easycdg.com/airport-guide/shopping-and-eating/), on which you can find more detailed information on opening hours.

[Incidentally, terminal 2E seems to be one of the best in which to sleep, according to various reviews on SleepingInAirports.](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/paris.htm) It therefore seems that you are in luck.

As you noted, there is a Sheraton Hotel at CDG. However t[he terminal is landside, between terminals 2E/F and 2C/D](http://www.sheratonparisairport.com/hotel-inside-paris-cdg-airport). More precisely, the hotel is on top of the RER/Train station at CDG. You'll therefore need to exit the airside portion of terminal 2E, and walk a couple hundred meters towards the station to access the hotel.

#### Go See Paris, Man

Having said all of this, with a 23-hour layover in CDG I would not hesitate to exit the terminal and go for a stroll in Paris. If you are wondering how long it will take you to get into Paris, [we have an excellent question on airport transfer on TSE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/transfers-between-paris-and-its-airports). Moreover, [here is another question with a sample quick-visit into Paris, covering Notre-Dame cathedral and Hotel de Ville](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43412/is-a-7-hour-layover-in-paris-long-enough-to-leave-the-airport-and-sightsee/43416#43416).